# How I fix onSaved?

Tags: flutter, dart

This code I mean in vscode say it not have this syntax of function
I think now onSaved use a onChanged
It be a Dart langugae I make code from flutter

```
  _inputField(context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Email",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
              filled: true,
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          onSaved: (String? email) {
            formKey.currentState?.save();
            profile.email = email!;
          },
```

Comment: what is the widget name?

Comment: I write from StatefulWidget

Comment: no I mean what is the name of widget that you try to use onSaved in it?

Comment: it be a build maybe

Comment: I want to keep profile same in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNjxDUmkseA&t=3650s I can't do it

Comment: and orignal code without onSaved can you look my github https://github.com/devjinx/appshopping/tree/main/lib/screen

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Widget's Documentation, which you are using.

The `TextField` Widget has an `onSubmitted()` method, and it does not have an `onSaved()` method.

The `TextFormField` (Text**Form**Field) Widget has an `onSaved()` method.

Hope this helps. :)